# Why is it desirable to have high g value for sensing applications, while high d value is desirable for actuation in piezoelectricity?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, materials

In piezoelectric materials, two parameters are defined to construct relations between electrical and mechanical energy conversions. These parameters are the charge constant d and the charge constant g. In literature, it is always stated that  high g value is desirable for sensing applications, while high d value is desirable for actuation. This is proved as follows:

d is defined in two ways : 
d= strain developed/ applied electric field 
Based on this definition, large d constants relate to large mechanical displacements which are usually sought in actuators.
also d is defined as : 
d= induced charge density/ applied stress 
Based on this definition, however, I can conclude that high d value is also desirable for sensing applications, as more charge is induced per applied unit stress.

---

Regarding g constant, it is also defined in two ways 
g= induced electric field/ applied stress 
Output voltage is obtained by multiplying the calculated electric field by the thickness of ceramic between electrodes. High g constants favor large voltage output, and are sought after for sensors.
The second definition is

g= strain developed/ applied charge density. 
Based on this definition, however, I can conclude that high g value is also desirable for actuating applications, as more strain is developed per applied unit charge density. 
So I got confused of what is stated in the literature. Am I wrong ?

Also, Based on the definitions of d and g : 
d= induced charge density/ applied stress
g= induced electric field/ applied stress 
I can say that g = epsilon* d ; (epsilon is the electric permittivity)
electric field  is equal to the charge density divided by the permittivity.
So what is the importance of defining 2 parameters?I think that defining one of them is adequate.